# Dry water using graphite

Tags: water, mixtures

[Dry water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_water) or "powdered water" is essentially a bunch of extremely small water droplets surrounded by $\ce{SiO2}$.

Some time ago, I was messing around and mixed some powdered graphite with water. (The graphite was obtained from a pencil, so it was not pure. Also I mixed the two substances with a stick, not with a high-speed blender.) When a droplet of this was splashed onto the table, it could be blown around with air and even held on the hand without breaking, until it was squished.

The important part of this is, that that droplet could be placed back into the original mixture of water and graphite powder, and it would roll around on the surface.

So does anyone know if it's possible to use powdered graphite rather than silica particles to make dry water? If is is, what properties are different from the ordinary powdered water?

Comment: Silica is highly hydrophilic, graphite is not quite like  that.

Comment: @Ivan But the 'dry water' uses hydrophobic silica particles (surface modified). I think that nanographite would be a suitable substitute.

Comment: I may end up doing something similar to this for a school project. If I decide to mix the graphite with water instead of ink, I will measure its conductance. I could post my results here, maybe.

Comment: Graphite for pencils is mixed with clay, which is largely composed of silicates. I don't know whether pure graphite powder would display the same behavior you describe.